# grafana - build tiles dynamically

Tags: grafana

We have e.g. 500 certificates to monitor, across several customers/environments/vm's.
In Grafana, I want to create a high overview of all certificates validation time left.

We'd like to use the '[status panel plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/vonage-status-panel/)':

[image]

Assume a prometheus query w this dummy result:

```
my_query{host="vm-1", cert_type="something", expire_days="230", job="certs"}
my_query{host="vm-2", cert_type="else", expire_days="10", job="certs"}
my_query{host="vm-1", cert_type="something", expire_days="20", job="certs"}
```

Then in this case, the dashboard would consist of 3 tiles.
However, right now, for each tile, we have to manually create the tile based on a custom search.  The tiles on the dashboard do not grow dynamically.

When another result is added to the prometheus query output, I'd like the tile to be automatically added to the dashboard. So we don't have to manually create/delete 500 tiles.

Any other tile is fine as well, as long as we got something along the lines of the shown status panel.

Would that be possible?

Comment: Have you considered usage of any other panel supporting automatic processing of results? Like "Stat" or "Polystat"?

Comment: Also, I don't know how you are getting your metrics, but your example doesn't look very good. You shouldn't store frequently changing value of days before certificate expiration in label: it should be metrics value. Good example is `probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry` of blackbox_exporter.

Comment: If using another panel is better, then ofc, we’ll use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use panel [Stat](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/stat/) to achieve similar result.

For this:

1. Add your query, for example `my_query`, and set its options (under query) to Type: **Instant**, Format: **Table**,
2. Add Transformation *[Convert field type](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#convert-field-type)*, Field **expire_days** as **Number**,
3. In the panel options:

   - *Value options*:

     - *Show*: **All values**,
     - *Limit*: some number bigger than number of your certificates,
     - *Fields*: **expire_days**
   - *Stat style*:

     - *Text mode*: **None**,
     - *Color mode*: **Background**,
   - Add following overrides for field **expire_days**:

     - *Thresholds > Thresholds*: set threshold values and colours as you'd like,
     - *Standard options > Color scheme*: **From thresholds (by value)**

Result is auto scalable - number of blocks shown on the panel is automatically adjusted for number of time series returned by query.

Result will look something like this:
[image]

Comment: holy dang, this is legendary.